# What is the memory overhead for analyzing a heap with jhat?

Tags: java, heap-memory, overhead, jhat

jhat is a great tool for analyzing Java heap dumps, but for large heaps its easy to waste a lot of time. Give jhat a runtime heap too small, and it may take 15 minutes to fail and run out of memory.

What I'd like to know is: **is there is a rule of thumb for how much -Xmx heap I should give jhat based on the size of the heapdump file?** Only considering binary heap dumps for now.

Some very limited experimentation indicates that its *at least 3-4 times the size of the heap dump*. I was able to analyze a three-and-change gigabyte heap file with -J-mx12G.

Does anyone else have more conclusive experimental data, or an understanding of how jhat represents heap objects at runtime?

data points:

- [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990609/running-out-of-memory-while-analyzing-a-java-heap-dump/2991376#2991376) indicates a 5x overhead, but my experimentation on late model jhats (1.6.0_26) indicates its not quite that bad
- [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026959/huge-heap-dump-11gb-jhat-failed-eclipse-mat-needed-help/6072209#6072209) indicates a ~10x overhead
- a colleague backs up the 10x theory: 2.5gb heap file fails with a -J-mx23G
- yet another colleauge got a 6.7 gb dump to work with a 30 gb heap, for a 4.4x overhead.

Comment: Have you tried the Eclipse Memory Analyzer as an alternative to jhat?

Comment: The Eclipse Memory Analyzer is good. An other alternative to open big heap dumps is [SAP Memory Analyzer](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/downloads?rid=/library/uuid/a0f47c83-5ef6-2910-2c89-b75d296edef9) or [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/). The last is not free.

Comment: I've used the Memory Analyzer, it's quiet good.

Comment: Ok, ok, I will definitely check out Eclipse's MAT. I am still interested in getting a handle on jhat though. The ability to drop a dump on any machine, fire up jhat and send around a link is very helpful.

Comment: Aren't Eclipse Memory Analyzer and SAP's project the same thing?